# How can I change the ambient display on Android phones with Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to develop an app for Android (using Java and android studio) just for fun, and I have a weird(ish) feature that I want to implement but have NO idea how. It's a relatively basic question, but at the same time a relatively complicated question: You know how you can like tap once on most android phones (when they're off) and it briefly shows like the time and date without the phone actually turning on? Is it possible to override that and tell the phone to display something else, like my own custom text? If so, can I also take it a step further and have the user interact with the elements/widgets, such as buttons and other input-based widgets? I've asked around and no one has been able to give me an answer, and I can't really find any apps that do this on the google play store, so I'm starting to think that its not possible